# Connecting two strings into one. C

Tags: c, string

How can I end a string in C? I made a function to connect 2 strings and make one. I read I should end string with '\0' but how to do this with declaration like this?

```
char* string1= "House";
char* string2= "is big";
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array big enough to fit both strings plus a single terminator. Copy the first string into the array. Concatenate the other string using [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat).

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```
char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
    {
        char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);
        strcpy(result, s1);
        strcat(result, s2);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: you should always typecast return memory of `malloc`

Comment: @rootTraveller [I disagree, rather strongly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @unwind yes but  `void*` don't get promoted in older version of C.

Comment: @rootTraveller I don't believe that to be true (C89 sure is "older", and does this conversion automatically), but even if it were I disagree with that mattering to how people program today. Requiring code to build on ancient compilers is not normal.